# What is the equivalent of LocalDB for MongoDB?

Tags: .net, mongodb, visual-studio, localdb

I find localdb useful for testing an ASP.NET web application.  I can load some test data and do some testing.  I am looking at Mongodb (No SQL) to use in conjunction with SQL Server.

Does MongoDB have a LocalDB equivalent? If the answer is no, then do any NoSQL databases have a LocalDB equivalent?

I have spent some considerable time Googling this.  I don't have a great deal of experience with MongoDB and hence the reason for the question.

Comment: Take a look at RavenDB https://ravendb.net a nosql db with in-memory db support.

Comment: You do realize that LocalDB is basically just a "cut down" install  of SQL server, given considerations that you don't need to set up more advanced options ever. Did you possibly then consider that other products don't need a "cut down install"? And maybe they just work pretty lean by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no LocalDB for MongoDB, have you tried using docker for development?

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 mongo
```

even before docker it's pretty easy to get mongodb setup for development:

```
mkdir \data\db
mongod
```

Comment: MVC has an app data folder.  Is it possible to store a MongoDB database file in app data?

Comment: there's no reason why you couldn't, however for development might be worth just creating some scripts to load in some json data?

Answer (score 1):

There is LiteDB which looks like a local equivalent for MongoDb:

https://www.litedb.org/